# Where is the code for gradient descent?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, gradient-descent

Running some experiments with TensorFlow, want to look at the implementation of some functions just to see exactly how some things are done, started with the simple case of `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer`. Downloaded the zip of the full source code from github, ran some searches over the source tree, got to:

```
C:\tensorflow-master\tensorflow\python\training\gradient_descent.py

class GradientDescentOptimizer(optimizer.Optimizer):

  def _apply_dense(self, grad, var):
    return training_ops.apply_gradient_descent(
```

Okay, so presumably the actual code is in `apply_gradient_descent`, searched for that... not there. Only three occurrences in the entire source tree, all of which are uses, not definitions.

What about `training_ops`? There does exist a source file with a suggestive name:

```
C:\tensorflow-master\tensorflow\python\training\training_ops.py

from tensorflow.python.training import gen_training_ops
# go/tf-wildcard-import
# pylint: disable=wildcard-import
from tensorflow.python.training.gen_training_ops import *
# pylint: enable=wildcard-import
```

... the above is the entire content of that file. Hmm.

I did find this file:

```
C:\tensorflow-master\tensorflow\python\BUILD

tf_gen_op_wrapper_private_py(
    name = "training_ops_gen",
    out = "training/gen_training_ops.py",
)
```

which seems to confirm such and such other files are object code, generated in the build process - but where is the source code they are generated from?

So this is the point at which I give up and ask for help. Can anyone familiar with the TensorFlow code base point me to where the relevant source code is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The implementation further goes to the native c++ code. Here's [`ApplyGradientDescent`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops_gpu.cu.cc#L29) GPU implementation (`core/kernels/training_ops_gpu.cu.cc`):

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct ApplyGradientDescent<GPUDevice, T> {
  void operator()(const GPUDevice& d, typename TTypes<T>::Flat var,
                  typename TTypes<T>::ConstScalar lr,
                  typename TTypes<T>::ConstFlat grad) {
    Eigen::array<typename TTypes<T>::Tensor::Index, 1> bcast;
    bcast[0] = grad.dimension(0);
    Eigen::Sizes<1> single;
    var.device(d) -= lr.reshape(single).broadcast(bcast) * grad;
  }
};
```

CPU implementation is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc) (`core/kernels/training_ops.cc`):

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct ApplyGradientDescent<CPUDevice, T> {
  void operator()(const CPUDevice& d, typename TTypes<T>::Flat var,
                  typename TTypes<T>::ConstScalar lr,
                  typename TTypes<T>::ConstFlat grad) {
    var.device(d) -= grad * lr();
  }
};
```