# how gradientdescentoptimizer computes the gradient in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I am really confused about how the gradientdescentoptimizer calculates the gradient and also applies the gradient in the next iteration. i know that we will be giving alpha(learning rate) as an argument, which will be multiplied by `(y - y_hat)`. but, how does the optimizer know, to which variable, it has to apply the gradient.

Comment: You might want to checkout `apply_gradient_descent` code: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47178371/712995

Comment: @Maxim, it looks pure c++ code. i tried understanding, but could not. i have not learnt c++ properly.