# Finding implementation of methods in Tensorflow

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow, gradient-descent

I want to change a bit minimization optimizers like `AdadeltaOptimizer`, which is used in Tensorflow.
I got the license but there is no code in lib, only reference, so how can I find the implementation? Here is Adadelta example of API:

```
@tf_export("train.AdadeltaOptimizer") class 
AdadeltaOptimizer(optimizer.Optimizer) 
Optimizer that implements the Adadelta algorithm.
See [M. D. Zeiler](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5701) ([pdf]
(http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.5701v1.pdf))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first entry point is [`python/training/adadelta.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/adadelta.py) from tensorflow main repo. But you may notice it's a python wrapper, all ops are actually implemented in native C++ and loaded in python (this is the usual practice in tensorflow, see for instance this question: [Where is the code for gradient descent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47178371/712995)).

For example, in [`core/kernels/training_ops.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc#L534) you can find CPU impelmentation of `ApplyAdadelta` op. GPU implementation of the same op is in [`core/kernels/training_ops_gpu.cu.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/982549ea3423df4270ff154e5c764beb43d472da/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops_gpu.cu.cc#L55):

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct ApplyAdadelta<GPUDevice, T> {
  void operator()(const GPUDevice& d, typename TTypes<T>::Flat var,
                  typename TTypes<T>::Flat accum,
                  typename TTypes<T>::Flat accum_update,
                  typename TTypes<T>::ConstScalar lr,
                  typename TTypes<T>::ConstScalar rho,
                  typename TTypes<T>::ConstScalar epsilon,
                  typename TTypes<T>::ConstFlat grad) {
    Eigen::array<typename TTypes<T>::Tensor::Index, 1> bcast;
    bcast[0] = grad.dimension(0);
    Eigen::Sizes<1> single;

    accum.device(d) = accum * rho.reshape(single).broadcast(bcast) +
                      grad.square() * (grad.constant(T(1)) -
                                       rho.reshape(single).broadcast(bcast));
    const auto update =
        (accum_update + epsilon.reshape(single).broadcast(bcast)).sqrt() *
        (accum + epsilon.reshape(single).broadcast(bcast)).rsqrt() * grad;
    var.device(d) -= update * lr.reshape(single).broadcast(bcast);
    accum_update.device(d) =
        accum_update * rho.reshape(single).broadcast(bcast) +
        update.square() *
            (grad.constant(T(1)) - rho.reshape(single).broadcast(bcast));
  }
};
```

If you'd like to patch C++ code, you'll have to rebuild `.so` library. To be able to run your new optimizer on both CPU and GPU, you'll have to touch and rebuild both.

Comment: And also I just need to rewrite c++ functitions if I want to make new adadelta instead of included in tensorflow?